# Need ADB command line to start a youtube video using browser

Tags: android, adb

I have an Adb shell command

adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d 'https://youtu.be/CSULRDoF8-g'

That does work. But when it calls the URL (a youtube video link) the Youtube app takes over the navigation instead of the browser.

I want the youtube video to be open via browser, not Youtube app. I am using Samsung Galaxy S7, the video can be played from eighter Chrome or Samsung stock browser.

Any clues? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can launch Chrome with that url as parameter using:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main "https://youtu.be/CSULRDoF8-g"
```