# Is it possible to control Android bluetooth device pairing via adb?

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, adb

I'm looking into automating certain Bluetooth activities via adb.

I have been able to successfully enable and disable Bluetooth using information found here: 
[android enable disable bluetooth via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259260/android-enable-disable-bluetooth-via-command-line) 
but need more capabilities and control than just enable/disable.

While looking for solutions I came across this post:
[Need ADB command line to start a youtube video using browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339474/need-adb-command-line-to-start-a-youtube-video-using-browser?rq=1)
 where chrome is controlled via intents/activities.

I've attempted a similar solution with Bluetooth by unpacking (using apktool) the Settings apk and the bluetooth apk, looking at their AndroidManifest.xml files for a list of their intents and activities - then using those intents and activities via adb,

e.g. (running shell as superuser)

```
am start -n "com.android.settings.bluetooth.RequestPermissionActivity/android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE"
```

Thus far, commands of this nature have either:

1) Failed outright, "unable to resolve intent" or similar issues

2) Led to a ">" prompt wherein I'm expected to give more input (though I'm not sure what I would enter there)

Ultimately, I'm seeking to control BT connections using adb (so as to be able to automate those tasks via scripts in the future). 
I am using a Google Pixel 2 (rooted).

If I am on the right track, any guidance or advice would be appreciated.
If I'm going about this completely wrong, feel free to let me know (and hopefully let me know where I should be looking instead).